# Le « super-milliardaire » et le billionnaire pour le « trillionaire » (en anglais): différences de sens, valeur du préfixe, adéquation de l'usage ?

Tags: anglais, nombres, société, préfixes, substantivation

> [...] à ce rythme, le premier « super-milliardaire » du monde «
>   pourrait voir son patrimoine dépasser le millier de milliards de
>   dollars dans 25 ans à peine »
>
> [ *[Oxfam](https://www.oxfam.org/en/campaigns/even-it/5-shocking-facts-about-extreme-global-inequality-and-how-even-it-davos) dénonce la richesse «indécente» de huit
>   multimilliardaires*, [*La Presse*](http://affaires.lapresse.ca/economie/international/201701/16/01-5059886-oxfam-denonce-la-richesse-indecente-de-huit-multimilliardaires.php), 16 janvier 2017 ]

Le mot employé par *Oxfam* en anglais est *trillionaire*. Dans un article d'il y a quelques années sur [*Slate.fr*](http://www.slate.fr/economie/78802/milliardaires-futur-argent) (*En 2063, le monde comptera 11 «super-milliardaires», selon le Crédit Suisse*), on traduit de la même manière un passage d'un document dont l'original en anglais, [*Global Wealth Report 2013*](https://publications.credit-suisse.com/tasks/render/file/?fileID=BCDB1364-A105-0560-1332EC9100FF5C83), parle de *trillionaires*. On se [rappellera](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=9-nI6-pQZOTM.html) qu'on a *million, milliard, **billion**, billiard* [pourquoi le correcteur affiche une faute], *trillion, trilliard, quatrillion/quadrillion*... jusqu'au [*googolplex*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=billion&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) ([10<sup>googol</sup>](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8360103) ou [10<sup>10<sup>100</sup></sup>](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gogolplex)), que l'unité de base choisie est normalement le multiple du *million*, et que cela peut différer de ce qu'on trouve en [Amérique](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=billion&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) du nord ([Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-srch?lang=fra&srchtxt=millier%2C%20million&i=&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=7&comencsrch.y=7)) en langue anglaise etc.

---

D'où vient cette représentation des nombres en substantif préfixé par « courte-échelle sur le cardinal inférieur », pour ainsi dire, pour désigner celui qui possède la richesse dont on dit l'indécence participer d'un degré supérieur, qu'on sait nommer cardinalement ; de quoi s'agit-il ?

- Y a-t-il une différence entre le *super-milliardaire* et le *billionn[aire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-aire)*
  ; y a-t-il une connotation particulière à *super-milliardaire* que billionnaire n'aurait pas ; est-ce une hésitation entre les échelles courtes et longues des grands nombres en langue française dans la presse écrite ; un usage particulier ; de la vulgarisation ?
- Que veut dire [*super*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/super-) dans *super-milliardaire* alors
  qu'on a déjà [*multi-*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/multi-) : est-ce beaucoup de multi, égal ou supérieur à mille milliards (soit un billion), ou de quel segment s'agit-il entre 10<sup>9</sup> et 10<sup>12</sup> ; pourquoi pas [*supra*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3111), « qui est d'un ordre supérieur, au-delà » ? La *BDL* parle de [productivité](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=1397) du premier avec des noms et adjectifs en « langue technique ou publicitaire » et
  du fait « qu'il entre dans la formation d'adjectifs et de noms des
  domaines scientifiques et techniques » pour le second.
- Peut-on présenter un exemple récent d'emploi du mot *billionnaire* dans une œuvre (de fiction...) ou une publication reconnue en français pour désigner celui/celle dont la valeur des avoirs se chiffre à un million de millions, ou mille milliards de [nom de la devise] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Y a-t-il une différence entre le super-milliardaire et le billionnaire ;

Oui, billionaire a été écarté par l'auteur car le mot n'est pas utilisé en français, tout comme billion. On recommande même parfois d'éviter de le faire, voir [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&__index=frt&srchtxt=billion&comencsrch.x=12&comencsrch.y=10), mais c'est inutile, personne ne le fait dans la vie courante. On dit « mille milliards » mais comme « mille-milliardaire » est douteux, « super-milliardaire » a été préféré par l'auteur de l'article, car facilement compréhensible. Au delà de mille milliards, on dira un million de milliards, un milliard de milliards, mille milliards de milliards et ainsi de suite.

> - Que veut dire super dans super-milliardaire alors qu'on a déjà multi-

Multi-milliardaire signifie « qui a plusieurs milliards » (TLFi: [multimilliardaire Plusieurs fois milliardaire et, par extension, richissime.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/multi-))

« Super-milliardaire » est une création de l'auteur. C'est pour ça qu'il met ce mot entre guillemets. Il signifie implicitement "plus que milliardaire" (c.f. [super-](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/super-)) sans plus de précision. Dans le cas de l'article, la valeur de la fortune doit être supérieure à mille milliards car c'est explicitement précisé :

> Selon l'ONG, à ce rythme, le premier « super-milliardaire » du monde « pourrait voir son patrimoine dépasser **le millier de milliards** de dollars dans 25 ans à peine ».

.

> - pourquoi pas supra, « qui est d'un ordre supérieur, au-delà » ?

*Supra-* est peu productif et risquerait d'être moins compris alors que « super-milliardaire » fait ici penser à super-héros qui est un mot très courant, comme d'autres en *super-*.

> - Peut-on présenter un exemple récent d'emploi du mot billionnaire dans une œuvre (de fiction...) ou une publication reconnue en français pour désigner celui/celle dont la valeur des avoirs se chiffre à un million de millions, ou mille milliards de [nom de la devise] ?

Probablement pas. Comme déjà indiqué, billion et trillion sont essentiellement absents du français.

> - billiard [pourquoi le correcteur affiche une faute]

Parce qu'il pense qu'il s'agit d'un [billard](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/billard), qui n'a pas de deuxième *i* en français. Billiard est inconnu de beaucoup de dictionnaires, ce qui n'est pas étonnant puisque son utilisation est rarissime.

Comment: Merci encore ! Au final le choix fait dans les articles n'est pas fondamental, le fait d'expliciter le millier de milliards plus loin rend ça cohérent. En voyant l'expression, j'ai pensé davantage à (super-milliard)aire, plutôt qu'à la catégorie supérieure à celle du milliardaire finalement, _plus que_ comme vous dites. Mes exemples ne font pas autorité en science etc. où on a la notation et des usages dont ceux que vous mentionnez. Je n'avais pas vérifié au LBU14 (598), mais il ne dit pas ce que _Le Petit Robert dit_, mais _rarissime_, sans doute, et les usages pré-1961, _parfois_...

Comment: il mentionne le [décret](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006061026) de 1961, contenant le tableau [suivant](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jo_pdf.do?id=JORFTEXT000000501821&pageCourante=04587), dont la note 3 A est incompatible avec la suggestion du _Petit Robert_, il me semble. Mais l'usage peut varier de ces normes et leur mention/analyse n'est pas requise pour répondre à la question posée. Enfin j'ai été rassuré par qq. exemples en sens contraire dont  [Huffington+LM](http://www.huffingtonpost.fr/2013/10/17/fortune-un-premier-billionnaire-dans-20-ans/).

Answer (score 1):

Pour moi *super-milliardaire* voudrait dire "au-delà du milliard" - c'est tout, autrement dit, plus que milliardaire. Je peux me tromper. Je ne crois pas que le terme soit très précis, mais ici, l'auteur indique clairement ce qu'il veut dire: plus de mille milliards, soit un *billion* (français, soit 10<sup>12</sup>).

Je crois que c'est un peu différent de *multi-*, que je comprends comme "plusieurs" - "multi-million" pour moi voudrait dire "quelques millions", peut-être moins de dix.

La wikipedia en français pourrait servir de référence ici, en particulier l'article "Noms des grands nombres", dont je vais reproduire un bout ici:

> Les billiards, trilliards, ... d'utilisation moins fréquente, se forment régulièrement sur les préfixes précédents: de manière régulière, un X-illiard vaut mille X-illions.
>   On a donc, de manière régulière :

[image]

Comment: Je crois que _super-_ est vague, et ne veut dire que "plus que".